# Skip value in RTF reporting

Tags: r

I have a data frame df for report in RTF format as:

```
df <-

ATRSLBL POPUL   CENTRE  BAGE    BAGEC1  SEX
Red     PPS     37201   75      3       1
Red     PPS     37201   71      2       2
Red     PPS     37201   73      2       1
Red     PPS     38201   66      2       2
Blue    PPS     37201   78      3       2
Blue    PPS     38201   71      2       2
Blue    PPS     38201   71      2       1
Blue    PPS     38201   64      1       2
```

I want to print it as:

```
ATRSLBL POPUL   CENTRE  BAGE    BAGEC1  SEX
Red     PPS     37201   75      3       1
        PPS             71      2       2
        PPS             73      2       1
        PPS     38201   66      2       2
Blue    PPS     37201   78      3       2
        PPS     38201   71      2       2
        PPS             71      2       1
        PPS             64      1       2
```

Can anyone help me please.

Comment: Hi akrun, thank you for your help. Can you please give the example for only variable ATRSLBL. It will help me for better understanding

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can do this with `data.table`.  We convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df)`), We get the logical index of `duplicated` 'ATRSLBL' and assign (`:=`) it to `''`.  We create the grouping variable (`cumsum(ATRSLBL !='')`), and get the row index of `duplicated` 'CENTRE', use that index to assign 'CENTRE' to `''` after converting the 'CENTRE' column to 'character'

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[duplicated(ATRSLBL), ATRSLBL := '']
i1 <- df[, .I[duplicated(CENTRE)] , cumsum(ATRSLBL!='')]$V1
df[, CENTRE:= as.character(CENTRE)][i1, CENTRE:= '']
df
#    ATRSLBL POPUL CENTRE BAGE BAGEC1 SEX
#1:     Red   PPS  37201   75      3   1
#2:           PPS          71      2   2
#3:           PPS          73      2   1
#4:           PPS  38201   66      2   2
#5:    Blue   PPS  37201   78      3   2
#6:           PPS  38201   71      2   2
#7:           PPS          71      2   1
#8:           PPS          64      1   2
```

NOTE: Here I am assuming the 'ATRSLBL' column as `character` class.

Comment: @Pascal Yes, you are right. I used a different data earlie

Comment: Thanks @akrun. Its really helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Here is one way with `dplyr`. I am not sure if `ATRSLBL` is character or factor. My assumption is that it is a factor. First, I converted `ATRSLBL` to character. Then, I replaced duplicated `Red` and `Blue` with `""`.  I also created a group variable using `cumsum()` in the first `mutate()` part. Using the group variable, I grouped the data and applied `replace()` for `CENTRE`. Here, I am telling R if row number of each group is not 1, replace whatever character to `""`. Hence, you keep information in the first row of each group. Then, you ungroup the data and delate the group variable using `select()`. I hope this will help you.

```
library(dplyr)
mutate(mydf,
       ATRSLBL = replace(as.character(ATRSLBL), which(duplicated(ATRSLBL) == TRUE), ""),
       group = cumsum(c(T, abs(diff(CENTRE)) > 1))) %>%
group_by(group) %>%
mutate(CENTRE = replace(CENTRE, which(row_number(CENTRE) != 1), "")) %>%
ungroup %>%
select(-group)

#  ATRSLBL  POPUL CENTRE  BAGE BAGEC1   SEX
#    (chr) (fctr)  (chr) (int)  (int) (int)
#1     Red    PPS  37201    75      3     1
#2            PPS           71      2     2
#3            PPS           73      2     1
#4            PPS  38201    66      2     2
#5    Blue    PPS  37201    78      3     2
#6            PPS  38201    71      2     2
#7            PPS           71      2     1
#8            PPS           64      1     2
```

**DATA**

```
mydf <- structure(list(ATRSLBL = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L), .Label = c("Blue", "Red"), class = "factor"), POPUL = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "PPS", class = "factor"), 
CENTRE = c(37201L, 37201L, 37201L, 38201L, 37201L, 38201L, 
38201L, 38201L), BAGE = c(75L, 71L, 73L, 66L, 78L, 71L, 71L, 
64L), BAGEC1 = c(3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L), SEX = c(1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L)), .Names = c("ATRSLBL", "POPUL", 
"CENTRE", "BAGE", "BAGEC1", "SEX"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```

Comment: Thanks @jazzurro. Its really helpful.

Comment: Can you please tell me if CENTRE is a character then what would be the procedure. Thanks.

Comment: @AbuNoman You need to check your data frame. Try `str(the name of your data frame)`. That will tell you if you have CENTRE as character or not. In my case, I had integer in this example.